# Full Mail Server Failover

Tags: debian, postfix, email-server, failover

I'm trying to find the best solution to allowing a mail server to still be fully operational even if it were to crash by switching to a fallback server.

We run our mail server on Debian using Postfix and Courier-IMAP.

I know about MX records and enabling relays as to not miss any new incoming emails. However I need to be able to still access the old emails.

Putting a load-balancer in front of 2 servers and setting up automatic fallback is a consideration but I'm not sure how well such a solution will play out for a mail server as I have little experience using LBs.

I'm not opposed to using GlusterFS or the like for the maildir so long as the performance impact is negligible. However I have heard / researched that such a solution comes with high performance cost.

Last requirement would be that the connection details while using a mail client shouldn't need to change when the fallback occurs. This requirement however is least important to all other factors.

Essentially I'm looking for an industry standard solution. If the industry has decided such a solution doesn't need to exist, any potential workarounds would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

1. Store your mailboxes on a replicated storage. Depending on your performance needs you have a few choices: if we stay in the open-source / software-defined realm, I'd recommend either a NFS export backed by Gluster (http://www.gluster.org) or a DRBD (http://www.drbd.org) device. Depending on the expected size of the mailboxes, Gluster might not be suited.
2. Use IMAP replication to have your mailboxes replicated and constantly synced between two servers, I recommend Dovecot (https://wiki.dovecot.org/Replication)

**The shared storage solution:**

Assuming that you go with DRBD, which has decent performances, you need to setup Linux-HA (http://www.linux-ha.org) to make sure that only one server is active at a time and only one server has mounted the DRBD device.
The MX record points to the floating IP managed by Linux-HA.

The SMTP/POP/IMAP services should read any accounting information (mailboxes, aliases, encrypted passwords) from the same replicated lookup service, like MySQL / LDAP.

This will be an active/passive cluster.

**The IMAP replication solution:**

Each mail server has its own independent local storage.
Setup two identical servers, make sure that Postfix and Dovecot read accounting information from the same replicated lookup service (MySQL / LDAP).
Setup Dovecot to replicate mailboxes across the two servers.

This will be an active/active cluster. In this case, incoming mail goes randomly to one of the two mail servers and end up in its local storage.
Periodically Dovecot Sync performs a two-way replication between the mails stored on each server and automatically solves conflicts.
There is a small time window (the interval between two syncs) during which some messages might be lost. It's up to you to decide if this is acceptable or not.